# Cleaner way to collect properties from object into two arrays without using `map` twice?

Tags: javascript, express

I have this block of code at the moment:

```
res.json({
    dates: rows.map(function (item) { return item.Date }),
    counts: rows.map(function (item) { return item.NewMembers })
});
```

This works, but it feels not correct, as the `rows` array is being iterated twice. How can I clean this up, and become more performant without iterating the same array twice?

This is using express, and `res.json` is the response from the route.

I have ES6 access if there's a newer methodology to handle this.

Comment: You could do it with `.reduce()`, but unless you know that that particular code is a performance problem I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use two arrays for collecting.

```
var dates=[], counts = [];

rows.forEach(function (item) { 
    dates.push(item.Date);
    counts.push(item.NewMembers);
});

res.json({
    dates: dates,
    counts: counts
});
```

Comment: @aw04, not incidently.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result={dates:[],counts:[]}   
 rows.forEach(function (item) {
 result.dates.push(item.Date);
 result.counts.push(item.newMembers);

 });
res.json(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using reduce :

```js
var rows = [{date : 'a', member : 'b'}, {date : 'a1', member : 'b1'}, {date : 'a2', member : 'b2'}];

var res = rows.reduce( (prev, curr) => { 
  prev.date.push(curr.date); 
  prev.member.push(curr.member); 
  return prev;
}, { date : [], member : [] } );

console.log(res);
```